# Arduino Uno GPRS shield connect to a specific webpage

Tags: arduino, gprs

I have a project where I use the [GPRS Arduino Quadband](http://www.cooking-hacks.com/index.php/documentation/tutorials/arduino-gprs-quadband) module to connect to a specific website.

I can send [AT commands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set) and connect to the server and receive a response like this:

```
Serial.print("AT+KTCPCFG=0,0,\"http://www.google.com"); // Returns HTTP ok response
```

However I am wondering how would I connect to a specific webpage like `www.domain_name.com/my_specific_page.php`. But when I try

```
Serial.print("AT+KTCPCFG=0,0,\"http://www.domain_name.com/my_specific_page.php");
```

I get a [DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) error that the server cannot be found. What other header information do I include to be able to say the following?

- Connect to domain x
- Go to page Y on domain x

Comment: does `Serial.print("AT+KTCPCFG=0,0,\"http://www.domain_name.com");` work? Maybe just the server is down.

Comment: No this does work the server is up and running, I can connect to he domain but I need to specifically connect to my_specific_page.php on the domain which is what fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer it was down to me not understanding http headers

When entering the information to connect to the domain you need to specify in the http request 
that the host is your domain name and the GET is the specific file on the server

It should be like this (CRLF means Carriage Return, Line Feed):

```
GET /my_specific_page.php HTTP/1.1[CRLF]

Host: www.domain_name.com[CRLF]

//Other header information
```